# JS-How to check if Braintree drop-in ui loaded correctly?

Tags: javascript, braintree

In the case that braintree drop-in ui does not load correctly, the form submit button can still be clicked. I want to catch whether drop-in ui loaded correctly and then enable/disable the button.

How can I detect whether braintree drop-in ui loaded correctly or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a cleaner solution:

1. Set submit button attribute disabled
2. Use [onReady](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/client-sdk/javascript/v2#global-setup) callback in braintree.setup() to enable the submit button.

Comment: what is the equivalent when using  braintree.dropin.create  method ?

Comment: are you referring to the drop-in UI? if so, according to the documentation, looks like you can pass in a callback as the second argument: 

https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/drop-in/setup-and-integration/javascript/v3#client-side-implementation

You can then pass a callback that does whatever you want to signal that the UI has been loaded. There also seems to be a promise version as well

Answer (score 2):

If you don't include any other child elements where your Braintree ui is inserted, you can use the script below to check that there are child elements (which the braintree setup should add) and will also check that the `braintree` object is defined on the `window`. Note: `childElementCount` requires a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/childElementCount) to support IE8.

html:

```
<div id="braintreeCompHere"></div>
```

script:

```
checkForBraintree('braintreeCompHere');

function checkForBraintree(btContainer) {
    var elBool = document.getElementById(btContainer).childElementCount > 0,
        btBool = typeof window.braintree !== 'undefined';

    return elBool && btBool;
}
```